# Doubts about color spaces and chroma subsampling

Tags: colorspace

Hy everyone, I have some questions about color spaces and chroma subsampling that I haven't been able to solve just by searching the web.

1. Are `YUV` and `YCbCr` the same thing? When I take a look at the information of a random MP4 video file with `ffmpeg` or `MediaInfo`, I see that the color space is indicated as `YUV`. Is that actually `YCbCr` since we're talking about a digital file?
2. It doesn't make any sense to say `RGB 4:2:0`, right? Because chroma subsampling only applies to the `YCbCr` color space, taking the (Cb, Cr) components, and deciding how many of them should be but in a 4x2 pixels region. Is that correct?
3. When `ffprobe` outputs that a video has a `bits_per_raw_sample` (or bit depth) of 8 bits with a `yuv420p` pixel format, what does it mean? What is the "raw sample" here? Is the 8 bits value referred to the number of bits used for each component (Y, Cb, Cr) before doing chroma subsampling? In that case, how should I calculate how many bits per pixel (or per 4x2 pixels region [?]) are used after chroma subsampling?

I hope it's ok to have multiple questions in the same post. Thank you.

Comment: Please split this up in to three questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Are YUV and YCbCr the same thing?* → strictly, no. The former is applied to analog signals, and the latter to digital. But media apps (like Mediainfo) use YUV as the designated term.

*It doesn't make any sense to say RGB 4:2:0, right?* → Not theoretically incoherent, but I haven't seen any codec that implements subsampling for RGB pixels except for Bayer RGB streams possibly. Don't know its details.

*What is the "raw sample" here?* → a stored single value of a pixel component i.e. any of R,G,B,Y,U,V (or alpha).

*Is the 8 bits value referred to the number of bits used for each component (Y, Cb, Cr) before doing chroma subsampling?* → it is the resolved bits per individual sample i.e. a 12-bit value has to be stored as a 16-bit datum, so 12 bits is the raw sample size and 16 bits is the coded sample size. 4 bits are for padding.

*how should I calculate how many bits per pixel* → in terms of luma/chroma resolution, it's the raw sample size. In terms of storage space for a raw uncompressed stream, you sum up the counts in the sampling scheme and divide by maximum count. Multiply by (no. of components x coded sample size).

So, for 4:2:2, that's

`(4+2+2) / (4+4+4) = 2/3` and then `2/3 x (3 x 8 bits) = 16 bits per sample`

Comment: Thank you. Just one thing: when you say that `a 12-bit value has to be stored as a 16-bit datum`, where does the 16 bits value come from?

Comment: Multiple of 8. Memory I/O and data operations are more efficient when working with byte-sized data.

Comment: So when we talk about 10-bit video, the actual sample is stored with 16 bits. Do you have any external resource about this you can point me to? Thanks

Comment: This is applicable for a raw uncompressed video stream. Strictly only true for raw streams in planar format. Packed formats (R, G and B values for each pixel are stored one after another) will also be padded if the total size of each pixel does not end on a memory access boundary. Doesn't apply to encoded data as those coded words don't map 1-to-1 to raw samples. Authoritative source is to look at source code of apps which encode and decode raw streams e.g. ffmpeg. Look in `libavcodec/rawdec.c`

Answer (score 0):

2nd question: RGB JPEG can use all kinds of subsamplings, including 4:2:0 with "center" G, B siting. It makes little sense, since we have better vision in green.